# Tradingview Pine script bar_index as a condition of itself

Tags: pine-script

I searched for weeks now but I cannot find a solution for my problem. So maybe you can help. :)

I have created an indicator which always should show the last 5 trading days. So when writing the script I wanted to create the simple condition: if the actual bar (on a daily chart) is the 5th bar before the realtime bar then start the indicator. The indicator then sums up percental changes from day to day and creates a line of 5 values. This is the idea but it seems there is no possibility to know if the actual bar is the 5th from realtime bar.

I tried to use the timenow variable and subtract 5 days converted in miliseconds but it does not work properly because of the weekend, trading holidays and so on where is no trading data available (and no candle). Furthermore it gets messy with the different time zones of the chart (i.e. UTC+2) and of the security (i.e. UTC-4). Simply working with bars would be the elegant way and much better in my opinion but maybe this solution is the only way to get the desired result.

Another idea was to work with a loop and store all data in an array but then I have the problem that you cannot plot the array because the plot function does not allow this.

So any idea how I can solve this problem? Frankly I cannot believe that this simple problem cannot be solved easily with a software which was designed to work with bars..

Cheers Karl

Comment: Please don't add answers to elaborate on your question. It's better to edit your original question and add the info there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to do something like this

```
//@version=5
indicator("Cumulative percentage change")

src = input.source(close, "Source")
len = input.int(5, "Length")

pct_change = 100 * ta.change(src)/src[1]
cumulative = math.sum(pct_change, len)

plot(pct_change, "pct_change", color.blue)
plot(cumulative, "cumulative", color.red)
```

which yields

[image: screenshot]

**Edit 1**
In answer to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72944833/tradingview-pine-script-bar-index-as-a-condition-of-itself/72945173?noredirect=1#comment128879759_72945173).

```
//@version=5
indicator("Cumulative percentage change")

src = input.source(close, "Source")
len = input.int(5, "Length")
t1  = input.symbol("EURUSD", "Symbol 1")
t2  = input.symbol("EURNZD", "Symbol 2")
t3  = input.symbol("EURCHF", "Symbol 3")

var float   cumulative1 = 0
var float   cumulative2 = 0
var float   cumulative3 = 0
var bool    draw        = false

value1 = request.security(t1, "", src)
value2 = request.security(t2, "", src)
value3 = request.security(t3, "", src)

delta1 = ta.change(value1)
delta2 = ta.change(value2)
delta3 = ta.change(value3)

// if bar_index >= last_bar_index - len - 1 and not draw
//     draw := true

if bar_index >= last_bar_index - len - 1
    if draw
        cumulative1 += 100 * delta1/value1[1]
        cumulative2 += 100 * delta2/value2[1]
        cumulative3 += 100 * delta3/value3[1]
    else
        draw := true

plot(draw ? cumulative1 : na, "cumulative1", color.red)
plot(draw ? cumulative2 : na, "cumulative2", color.green)
plot(draw ? cumulative3 : na, "cumulative3", color.blue)
```

which yields

[image: 5 datapoints]

Comment: The problem is I need each seperate data point to draw the indicator line ( to see how it developed over the shown period) and I only want to display the last 5 data points.

Comment: Added Edit 1 section to my answer.

Comment: Hi Bjorn!! Yes that was what I was looking for!! I did not know that in version 5 exists the "last_bar_index" !! :) This is new to version 4! Do you know if there are more new bar_index variables in version 5? Thanks a lot!! To both of you!! :)

Comment: No, only `bar_index` and `last_bar_index`. You can find all keywords/functions in the [Pine Script™ language reference manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/).

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to find that a bar is 5th bar before realtime bar.
You can directly pick the value of last 5 bars after reaching the realtime bar. Here is an example EURUSD cumulative change sum plotted for 30 days

```
//@version=5
indicator("30 Day Change By Rohit")
var sumofchange=0.0
if barstate.islast
    for j = 1 to 30 
        i=30-j
        newsum=sumofchange+(close[i]-close[i+1])/close[i+1]
        line.new(bar_index-i,sumofchange,bar_index-i+1,newsum)
        sumofchange:=newsum
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Rohit please see my answer to Bjorn. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Hi Rohit, that could work!! :) I have to try to change my indicator to this method. This solution looks like what I wanted to do with an array and the plot function. But it does not work with the plot function but line.new seems to work. In any case I wonder why it is not possible to identify the 5th bar from realtime while the script is running, this would help in many situations, don´t you think?

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem/requirement and decided to solve it in a different way.

I simply created a section of code in a if (barstate.islast) test. Thus wait until the last bar (islast=true) and you can then process backwards as far as you need. Thus don't try to solve the problem as the script processes bar-by-bar. Wait until the end and then process backwards. You can do that in a for loop. Thus

```
if (barstate.islast)
    for i = 0 to 4
         [code required to perform function]
```

You can use [i] to get previous bar values.

If you are going to process a lot of historical bars you may need to set "max_bars_back =" in the indicator statement at the start of the script